# How exit from debugging with preventing execution next code?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Let me explain. I'm writing code and added breakpoint before some ajax query.
I've analysed data from variables and now want to prevent ajax query execution, but if I resume code, it will be executed.
I can refresh page and ajax query will not be send, but how to do this without loosing page changes on the fly?

Comment: Do you want to debug JavaScript code before sending the ajax request ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you call your `AJAX` function?

If you call it like this

```
function AJAXCaller() {
    ... // CODE THAT ANALYZE THE DATA
    $.ajax({ ... });
    ... // CODE CONTINUATION
}
```

then you could probably add some `variable` as a `flag` to decide whether to run the `AJAX` or not like this

```
var runAJAX = true;

function AJAXCaller() {
    ... // CODE THAT ANALYZE THE DATA
    if(runAJAX) {
        $.ajax({ ... });
    }
    ... // CODE CONTINUATION
}
```

then you could add the `breakpoint` at the `if(runAJAX) {`, then if you decide not to run the `AJAX` call, change the `runAJAX` value using the `console`

Comment: Change javascript in devtools on the fly? I had not thought about it. Looks like good idea)

Comment: @Kein, yes you can try changing the value to continue or skip the `AJAX` call from the console in the developer options, hope it could help solve your problem